# sed/awk from specific line and column

Tags: awk, sed

I want to print entire 2nd row starting from the 8th character

Example:

```
1234567890
12 45 7foobar
1234567890
```

Output:

```
foobar
```

I tried `sed -n '2p'` it prints the entire 2nd row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cut` to only get what's after the 8th character:

```
$ sed -n "2p" test | cut -c 8-
foobar
```

Comment: This worked, Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

With sed:

```
sed -n '2s/.\{7\}//p' file
```

With awk:

```
awk 'NR==2{print substr($0,8)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by 2 methods awk and python

```
awk 'NR==2{sub(/^.{7}/,"",$0);print $0}' filename


python

#!/usr/bin/python
import re
m=re.compile(r'.{7}')
k=open('filename','r')
j=[]
for i in k:
    j.append(i.strip())

print re.sub(m,"",j[1])
```

output

```
foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

**grep**

```
$ grep -zoP '\A(?:.*\n){1}.{7}\K.*' file | tr -d '\0'

$ grep -m2 ^ file | tail -n 1 | cut -c8-

$ grep -Pom2 '.{7}\K.*' file | tail -n 1
```

**Python**

```
$ python3 -c 'print(open("file").read().splitlines()[1][7:])'
```

**perl**

```
$ perl -lne 'print(unpack("x7A*")), last if 2..2' file
```

**sed**

```
$ sed -e '
    /\n/{s/.$//;q;}
    2G;//s/./\n/7;D
  ' file
```

**bash builtins**

```
N=1
while IFS= read -r l; do
  case $N in
    2)
      printf '%s\n' "${l:7}"
      break;;
  esac
  (( N++ ))
done < file
```

Working:

- grep slurp the file, skips the first line, skips 7 characters ub the 2nd line, and puts the remaining characters on that line in the output bag.
- grep prints 2 matches, which are whole lines, then grab the tail, and chop it's first 7 characters by means if cut.
- python slurps the file, splits it into lines, picks the 2nd, and prints 8th char onwards.
- perl unpacks the 2nd line and ignores the leading 7 chars, and prints every char after that.
- bash builtins is self explanatory.